# Visual studio hangs when editing any document in a specific solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, freeze

After I closed a specific solution and reopened it, it open without any problem but when I tried to edit any document the first keystroke on the code editor cause the visual studio 2010 to become completely unresponsive, and I had to end the program. I tried opening that solution many times but it still hangs till after restarting the PC. any other solution is working fine it is just this solution that cause the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete the (SolutionName).suo File in the Solution Folder and try to reopen the solution.

Maybe some User Settings of the Solution are corrupted

Comment: thanks for that , it worked but i waited long time till it parsed the solution files, thanks

Comment: Yes this is correct, the new "first opening" is loading a Little bit longer. But if you reopen it now it should load faster